# Is it possible to define a different Reroute.key.field.name per postgres table?

Tags: debezium

Debezium by default uses the primary key as partition key, however some tables of mine should be paritioned by a different key (e.g. user)

hence I wanted to use: `transforms.Reroute.key.field.name=user_id` for that specific table only, and all of the rest would keep using the primary key

Docs:
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/configuration/topic-routing.html#_example

However I'm not very clear on how to apply that transformer only to one table, but not all others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of re-routing, you could specify the [message.key.columns](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-property-message-key-columns) connector option for customizing the columns that make up the message key for specific tables.

```
message.key.columns=inventory.customers:user_id
```

Comment: But doesnt the message key need to be Unique ? 
Whereas the partition key doesnt ? 
I'm a little confused here as i have the same need, a series of messages about a User, partitioned by that User Id